# UINavigationController buttons disappear when layoutIfNeeded before modal presentation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

Odd thing I am noticing:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myRootViewController)
navController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In above code I am seeing the navigation controller bar button not showing when I add the layoutIfNeeded()

The reason I am trying to add this is I am finding the root view controller's view lays itself out while the modal presentation is happening. When I add the layoutIfNeeded it does the view layout before presenting which fixes my original problem.

Comment: Did you try doing navController.view.layoutIfNeeded() in the completion closure of the present method?

Comment: I have tried this, the nav button does not appear.

Comment: Another thing I would try is to throw navController.view.layoutIfNeeded() in the viewDidAppear: of the view controller you are presenting.

Comment: Another thing I would try is to dispatch navController.view.layoutIfNeeded() on the main thread in the completion closure of the present method

Comment: I think your suggestion to add myRootViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded() in viewDidAppear seems to have fixed it :D , actually put it in viewWillAppear but its fixed it. Feel free to post it as an answer and Il marked it as solved. Not exactly what you suggested but its fixed.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try throwing navController.view.layoutIfNeeded() in the viewDidAppear:/viewWillAppear: of the view controller you are presenting and it should fix it.